# Why not always use #when_present.click with watir-webdriver?

Tags: ajax, watir, watir-webdriver

The `when_present` method polls the DOM every .1 seconds (by default) until the desired element is present. Other than the .1 second delay incurred by using it, is there any reason to use the standard `.click` method without `when_present`?

Why shouldn't I just make my own `.better_click` method that incorporates both waiting and clicking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no reason for you to not wait for whatever you want to wait for in your methods.

The original Watir api was blocking for page loading, and javascript interaction was not as important. The current implementation of Watir is closely tied to selenium-webdriver, so most of the behaviors of selenium are duplicated in Watir. Some developers like the added control over exactly what they are waiting for at all times.